# Parallel Index Creation in SQLite3

Tags: database, sqlite

- I have a ~40Gb database with around 100 tables.
- Indexing a table (on all columns) takes roughly 30 minutes.
- I have 64 cores in my server.

At the moment, the INDEX creation process takes roughly 2 days (while database creation takes around 5 hours...) so its an extreme bottleneck in my pipeline. I'm trying to think of ways to parallelise the process to use more than 1 core at a time. Here's what I thought of so far:

- Turn off all write locking (somehow?) and use multiple processes to CREATE INDEX. Since their different tables it might be OK.
- .dump each table from the main database into its own little database (containing just one table), index them separately on different cores, join them all back together (somehow?)
- Optimise the existing database (somehow?) to help the indexer do its thing faster. Could be moving the db over to SSD and using a single big CPU to computer the index (might save a day), or something like sorting the rows on database creation? Obviously not a parallel solution, but at this point i'll take anything.

**EDIT:**
Im using SQLite version 3.3.6

Comment: It is unclear, do you need to create indexes only once or repeat the process time to time? If you need to repeat, then what kind of an apllication it is that requires rebuilding of all indexes from scratch?

Comment: I need to create the indexes only once for my database (once a table is added, it is never updated), but the whole 40Gb database is made from time to time with new/different data

Comment: You also wrote you're creating index on all columns in the table, is this necessary? Indexes are usually created for a limited set of columns.

Comment: OK, then your suggestions 1 and 2 seem to be workable. But what if you first create empty table, then create index, then insert data? You won't have to build an index on the big data, it will be updated step by step as table grows.

Comment: With a database of that size I would think about moving to a "real" database server (e.g. Postgres) instead of using an in-process database like SQLite

Comment: a_horse - Postgres is unfathomably faster - but im writing software for other people who may/maynot have access to postgres or the ability to install any software than what they're given. So i support both postgres and Sqlite3, but the sqlite3 is way slow.

Andrei - I will give that a shot and post times here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite never allows multiple writers, and merging databases is not possible.

SQLite 3.8.7 or later can use multiple threads for sorting, if [enabled](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_threads).
This might or might not help.